# Magento 2 + how to include Bootstrap CSS on top position

Tags: magento2, magento-layout-xml

I am adding bootstrap css file via `default.head.blocks.xml`

File including successfully but css file is showing  after `styles-m.css`.

But i want to include it top one position.
Like

```
bootstrap.min.css

calandar.css

styles-m.css
```

[image]

`default_head_blocks.xml` code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>  
    <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <css src="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="js::custom-theme.js"/>
</head>
```

Please help me how it is possible to to include `bootstrap.min.css` on first position.

Comment: It's kinda complicated this answer helps for understanding https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217131/load-custom-css-after-style-l-css-for-home-page/217180#217180 there is a module you can use making ordering easier but not sure how current it is https://github.com/quickshiftin/mage2-ordered-assets

Comment: Using media="all" is not helping. Any other solution?